# Is it possible to send CAN messages out of a callback function?

Tags: matlab, timer, callback, simulink, can-bus

I have following problem: I would like to send CAN messages out of a callback function. This callback function is called by an timerobject. Everytime when the callback function is executed it should send the CAN message.

I coded:

```
canch = canChannel('PEAK-System', 'PCAN_USBBUS1'); 
configBusSpeed(canch, 1000000)  
start(canch) 

canch.Database = canDatabase('\\psf\Home\Desktop\02 CAN DBC\CAN4.dbc'); 

message = canMessage (canch.Database,'IPSS_RX_1_1ms'); 

transmitPeriodic(canch,message, 'On', 0.01); 

T= timer('ExecutionMode','fixedrate','Period',0.2,...
         'TimerFcn',@TEST_timer_callback_fcn,'StopFcn','disp(''Timer has stopped'')');

start(T)
```

Callback function:

```
function TEST_timer_callback_fcn(src,event)

message.Signals.In_ti= 39;
```

The CAN Channel starts - but the message is not send.

Can somebody help?

Comment: In what function do you have your callback function defined? Is it a sub-function of your main script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your timer function simply doesn't have access to the `message` object (i.e. it exists in a different scope). One option is to [nest your timer function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) within a function where you initialize `message`. Alternatively, you can pass `message` to your timer function. You could do this by changing the timer creation line to this:

```
T = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedrate','Period',0.2,...
          'TimerFcn',@(~,~) TEST_timer_callback_fcn(message),...
          'StopFcn','disp(''Timer has stopped'')');
```

And the callback function to this:

```
function TEST_timer_callback_fcn(message)

  message.Signals.In_ti= 39;
```

Comment: I just passed message to my timer function and it works like you said.

Comment: @R.Scott: Great! Seeing as you're relatively new to the site, just wanted to let you know that you can mark an answer as accepted when it solves your problem. More useful info about the site can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).